# What is the recommended/best process in moving SharePoint 2013 from one domain to another in Azure?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell

There one unique scenario we are facing, where we have SharePoint 2013 on Azure along with SQL too. We have 2 WFE, 2APP and 2 SQl in Azure of domain called xyz.com.

Scenario 1:We need to migrate/move them(SP2013) to New **Azure tenant** which has a different domain name called ABC.com, however we still gonna move XYZ.com vanity domain to new Azure tenant (kind of additional domain to ABC.com). Here Users will still login with XYZ.com only (old domain).

Can someone please help me to outline the steps.

Scenario 2:  We need to migrate/move them to New **Azure tenant** with new domain called **ABC.com**. Here users will get **new domain addres**s as login. Can anyone of you please guide all the steps in this situation?